# Calculating feedback resistors for op-amp based voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, resistors, voltage-regulator, potentiometer

I need to design a voltage regulator with an output range of 20-25V. I managed to re-create this ciruit from a course, but I'm stuck on calculating resistor values.

[image]

These are the formulas I'm given in the course, but so far all my calculations have led to a dead end. Needless to say I really, really suck at maths. Ignore the already present values in the screenshot above, they're random.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First off, a 741 will never work. Between the feedback network and the load, the op amp needs to provide roughly 50 mA, which is way beyond a 741's capabilities.

To do this the easy way, replace R1 with a 9k resistor. When the op amp is running properly, the voltage across this resistor will be 9 volts, for a total current of 1 mA. When the output is at 20 volts, the voltage across pot and R2 will be 11 volts. Since the current through these components must also be 1 mA, the total resistance must be 11k. Likewise, at 25 volts the resistance must be 16k. The difference is 5k, so that's the pot value, and the remainder is 11k, so that's R2. Any other set of values may be found simply by multiplying each of the three resistances by the same amount.

To address the current problem, simply add and NPN transistor like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh3FoB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For what you're doing, almost any NPN will work, such as a 2N3904, although it will get pretty warm. If you decide to drive a lower resistance, you'll need to calculate the power dissipation of the NPN. And be aware that if you accidentally short the load resistor, you will instantly kill the transistor.

Comment: I chose a 741 because it's the only one I knew of. What else should I use?
Also, what exactly is the transistor for?

Comment: Actually, a 741 should work OK in this circuit. The transistor (roughly) acts as a current amplifier. With a nominal current gain of about 100, its emitter can source 50 mA with a base current of .5 mA, and that is well within the capabilities of a 741.

Comment: Ok, I've replaced the resistors with the values above and for an input voltage in the range of 30-40V, I get an output of 16-25V. I need 20-25V and have no idea how to stop it from going below 20V.

Comment: First, I left out the 9-volt reference, but I assumed you'd know you need it. Is it still there? I've edited the schematic. When you vary the input (30 to 40 volts) does the voltage at the pot wiper, and the - input, change? Finally, make sure you have some capacitance on the input voltage, as close to the 741 as you can get it. A 0.1 uF ceramic and a 100 uF electrolytic is a good start.

Comment: The 9Vdc voltage is still there. It's only a PSPICE simulation so I don't think the type of capacitors matter much. It's all a semester project for a computer-aided design course. And yes, the pot wiper varies as a global parameter.

Comment: You're doing something wrong in your simulation. I've run the circuit, and the output is rock-steady over 30-40 volts. Is it possible that you've connected the pot as a variable resistor rather than a pot?

Comment: This is what the circuit looks like right now. [link](http://imgur.com/Y17N536).
Anyway, according to the equations I originally posted, for R1=9k, R2=11k and Pot=5k, the minimum output voltage is 16V. Or I may have miscalculated again. Still, the simulation shows 16.

Comment: You are, I'm afraid, correct, and I messed up. The pot should not be connected as a 3-terminal pot, but rather as a variable resistor for my approach to work. I've edited my schematic.

Comment: I'll try it this way once I have acces to the PC on which I have the software installed, but that won't be until monday.